# Credentials Error on Copy-Item in Background Job

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell Script that invokes a function on multiple Servers as a Background job.

Inside this function, there is a `Copy-Item` which always fails with the following Error Message:

`Username or Passwort is incorrect.`

The Destination where I want to copy my items to is a network share on a synology NAS.

It's a bit weird because the User that runs the Background jobs has full acess to the destination share by default (and I made sure that it really is that user that runs it by outputing `whoami` to a log file)

However, I also expicitly loaded my credentials inside the Background Job Scriptblock again and created a PSDrive to the destination to make sure I definetly have access, and I also added Credentials to my `Invoke-Command`. What's going on?

Here's my code:

```
$Sources = @{
    "HV-Server" = Invoke-Command -ComputerName DC { Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'HV*'" } | Where-Object {
        Test-Connection $_.Name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
}

$Destinations = @{
    "default" = "\\nas\Backup\VHDX"
}

. "\\server\install$\Powershell-Scripts\Functions\Security\Get-CustomCredential.ps1"
$Cred = Get-CustomCredential domain\myuser

Function Copy-VHDXToNAS {

    Param(
        [hashtable]$DestinationTable
    )

    Import-Module "Hyper-V"

    $BackupResult = Get-VM | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike 'nob*' } | Get-VMHardDiskDrive | 
    Where-Object { !$_.Path.StartsWith("\\") } | ForEach-Object {

        . "\\server\install$\Powershell-Scripts\Functions\Security\Get-CustomCredential.ps1"
        $Cred = Get-CustomCredential domain\myuser

        $Destination = $DestinationTable.Get_Item($_.VMName)
        if (!$Destination) { $Destination = $DestinationTable.Get_Item("default") }
        New-PSDrive Nas -Root $Destination -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $Cred > $null
        $Destination = Join-Path $Destination $_.VMName
        New-Item $Destination -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue > $null

        Try {
            Copy-Item $_.Path $Destination -Force -ErrorAction Stop
            $Result = "SUCCESS"
        }
        Catch {
            $a = whoami
            $Result = "ERROR: " + $_.Exception.Message + $a
        }

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            VMName = $_.VMName
            VHDXName = Split-Path $_.Path -Leaf
            Destination = $Destination
            Result = $Result
        }
    } 

    $BackupResult
}
    
$AllHosts = $Sources.Get_Item("HV-Server")
$Jobs = foreach ($HVHost in $AllHosts) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $HVHost -ScriptBlock ${function:Copy-VHDXToNAS} -ArgumentList $Destinations -AsJob -Credential $Cred
}
$JobResult = $Jobs | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Are you on a domain env?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes. All the Servers I connect to are in the domain environment

Comment: This simply seems like a double hop issue

Comment: How do you run your script as a background job? Do you use the task scheduler?

Comment: @DougMaurer I was thinking about that too, but I thought If I import my Credentials inside the Scripting Block, that shouldn't be a problem anymore. However I look into that some more

Comment: @Thomas yes, from Task Scheduler, with "run wheter user is logged in or not" and as Domain admin credential

Comment: @SimonS Does your domain admin account have the user right to log on as a batch job? You can look it up with `secpol.msc` under _Local Policies > User Rights Management_. Normally, a domain admin does not have this right. But an account needs this right in order to "run wheter user is logged in or not". You get this right by adding the account to the _Backup Operators_ group (often rather bad idea) or adding a particular account to this right manually or by GPO.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by DougMaurer, it really was a second-hop issue. I thought by renewing the credentials inside the Scriptblock I won't have the second hop issue, but I did.

In [this Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.1#pssessionconfiguration-using-runas) they talk about the second-hop problem and how to resolve it. I used the `PSSessionConfiguration` way [that is described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sergey_babkins_blog/another-solution-to-multi-hop-powershell-remoting)

Basically you create a Session Configuration on your Remote Server with the following command:

```
$ConfigurationSplat = @{
    Name = "Your.ConfigurationName"
    Force = $true
    MaximumReceivedDataSizePerCommandMB = 200MB
    MaximumReceivedObjectSizeMB = 200MB
    RunAsCredential = $Cred
}
Register-PSSessionConfiguration @ConfigurationSplat
```

And then you can use the `ConfigurationName` in your `Invoke-Command` like so:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $HVHost -ConfigurationName "Your.ConfigurationName" -ScriptBlock ${function:Copy-VHDXToNAS} -ArgumentList $Destinations -AsJob -Credential $Cred
```

And that fixes the second-hop problem.